# How to place matplotlib legend according to coordinate

Tags: matplotlib

I have several plots and one of these showed below:
[Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFO4a.png)

Problem is I have many plots and I need to put the legend differently according to the position where x=0 and line of x=0 may vary in different plots.

How can I achieve this?

besides, bbox_to_anchor just allow me locate relatively to the fig, but have no idea of the inside (x,y) coordinate.

This is the part plotting:

```
ax.errorbar(x=x, y=y_erd, yerr=e_erd, fmt='-o',ecolor='orange',elinewidth=1,ms=5,mfc='wheat',mec='salmon',capsize=3)
ax.errorbar(x=x, y=y_ers, yerr=e_ers, fmt='-o',ecolor='blue',elinewidth=1,ms=5,mfc='wheat',mec='salmon',capsize=3)
ax.legend(['ERD', 'ERS'], loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.85),fontsize='x-small')
ax.axhline(y=0, color='r', linestyle='--')
```

Comment: one way I can think of is convert the (x,y) coordinate to parameters of bbox_to_anchor.

Comment: Add the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have created a code to calculate the zero position of the x and y axes using a simple sample as an example. First, get the tick values for each axis. Then, use the obtained value to get the index of zero. The next step is to calculate the position of the tick marks for the difference between the minimum and maximum values. From the array, we obtain the coordinates based on the zero index we obtained earlier. Set the obtained coordinates to `bbox_to_anchor=[]`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 500)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, label='x=0,y=0')

xticks, yticks = ax.get_xticks(), ax.get_yticks()
xpos, ypos = 0, 0

for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(xticks, yticks)):
    if x == 0:
        xpos = i
    if y == 0:
        ypos = i
print(xpos, ypos)

x_min, x_max = ax.get_xlim()
xticks = [(tick - x_min)/(x_max - x_min) for tick in xticks]
y_min, y_max = ax.get_ylim()
yticks = [(tick - y_min)/(y_max - y_min) for tick in yticks]

print(xticks[xpos], yticks[ypos])
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=[xticks[xpos], yticks[ypos]], loc='center')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: There may be other, better ways to do this, but if my answer helped you, please accept it as the correct answer.